# SSL Apache HTTPD to SSL Weblogic Managed Servers Call

Tags: apache, https, weblogic, httpd.conf, mod-ssl

I want to setup SSL Apache HTTPD -> SSL Weblogic Managed Server.

While opening UI via https Apache HTTPD, getting backend server not available.

Note :

1. I have ssl module and related modules enabled on httpd end. Weblogic Managed Server SSL is also working because we deployed a middleware component and able to fetch the data from postman/soap UI/curl using https Weblogic Managed server IP and port with API of middleware.
2. I am able to implement SSL Apache HTTPD -> Non SSL Weblogic Managed Server and can able to open UI with https Apache HTTPD.

Comment: The first action is to check WebLogic Server's logs and see if you have any issue with your ssl configuration.
You can also check weblogic access logs to check that your resquest hits the managed servers.

Comment: The request is not coming to managed servers, so logs are not getting generated.

Comment: can you share your weblogic config into your httpd conf file ?

Comment: ERROR msg from httpd log


[weblogic:error] [pid 5338:tid 139736046049088] nzos_OpenWallet(file:<my-wallet-path-location>/mywallet) failed (28759)
[weblogic:debug] [pid 5338:tid 139736046049088] orassl.cpp(78): 0x236afb0: SSL context destroy
[weblogic:error] [pid 5338:tid 139736046049088] wl_ssl_init: The SSL create context failed status: 2
[weblogic:crit] [pid 5338:tid 139736046049088] (20014)Internal error (specific information not available): WL SSL Init failed for server: (null) on 0
[weblogic:error] [pid 5338:tid 139736046049088] Error Initializing SSL: Return value is -2

Comment: I created my wallet for weblogic CA using orapki command but apache httpd not able to understand..